# How to check if id exist in CodeIgniter Cart when there are more items in the cart?

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkout, cart

I have the same problem. the code does not work when there are more items in the cart. If there is only one product in the cart everything works.

Can anyone help me solve this?

```
public function Checkout()
{

    if (count($this->cart->contents())>0)
    {
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item)
        {       

            if($item['id'] == 2 or $item['id'] == 100)
            {

                $this->parser->parse('checkout',  isset($data) ? $data : NULL) ;

            }else{

                redirect('app/cart_configuration') ;

            }

            if($item['id'] == 200 && $item['id'] == 100)
            {
                 redirect('app/cart_configuration') ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first conditional inside the `foreach` loop. If the condition returns `true`, you make a call to `parse`, if it's not, you redirect to another page. As soon as the first condition is `false`, you stop script execution and redirect to another page. So depending on the order of items in the cart, you'll see redirection at different points. This is probably not what you want?

Also, take a look at your second conditional inside the `foreach` loop. It will always return `false`. Just guessing again, but this is probably not what you want.